# php redirecting to same page after login failed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to redirect to the same page after login failed,but instead I get redirected to `/login.php`.Here is my code:
Index.php:

```
<body>

    <h1><strong>Login</strong></h1>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST"> 
        <table id="mytable">
            <tr>
                <td><select name="type">

                    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                    <option vale="User">User</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br><br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" ><br><br> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Login.php:

```
?php
require 'ceva.php'; 

    $type=$_POST['type'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

//if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
//{

$sql= "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username ='$username' and password='$password' and type='$type'";  // selecteaza din baza de date login
$rezultat= mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

while($rand=$rezultat->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    if($rand['username'] == $username && $rand['password'] == $password && $rand['type'] == 'Admin') //verificare array
    {
        header("Location: admin.php"); //muta in pagina admin.php
    }else if ($rand['username'] == $username && $rand['password'] == $password && $rand['type'] == 'User'){
        header("Location: user.php");
    }else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

If credentials are correct I get redirected to `user.php` or `admin.php` just fine,but if they are wrong I should be redirected to `index.php`

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection and being compromised by using plain text passwords.

Comment: Btw, you have an extra `</form>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query only produces rows, that actually match username, password and type. So the while loop only runs if the credentials are correct. You need to put the redirect to index.php after it.

```
while($rand=$rezultat->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    if($rand['username'] == $username && $rand['password'] == $password && $rand['type'] == 'Admin') //verificare array
    {
        header("Location: index.php");header("Location: admin.php"); //muta in pagina admin.php
        exit;
    }else if ($rand['username'] == $username && $rand['password'] == $password && $rand['type'] == 'User'){
        header("Location: user.php");
        exit;
    }
}
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Side note: Best to add `exit;` after each header.